# how can I manage to read my Microsoft office documents in Libre office without any problems?

Tags: libreoffice

The thing is that some documents appear well but some others not. Instead of normal letters there are strange symbols

Answer (score 1):

The only safe methods to read correctly an MS document are:

1. Buying Microsoft Office and a OS that support that, and maybe running it in a virtual machine.
2. Using Office365 online on your Linux machine (it works, but keep in mind that Word online, for example, can't support the full Word features).
3. Asking your peer to send the documents in other formats (`ODS`, etc.), taking into account that the same limitation of point 2 applies.
4. If just for reading, ask your peers to send you `PDF`s. These are perfectly compatible most of the time (if fonts are embedded).

So unfortunately the answer is that there is no LO-MSO guarantee of compatibility at all; what you have in Libre Office is a best-effort thing that works reasonably well sometime, badly some other time. It is getting better and better, but it is a moving target.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question tbh :/

Comment: @tim It answers **this** question - maybe not your other one (this is why I didn't write an answer there).

Comment: "how can I manage to read my Microsoft office documents in Libre office without any problems?" is not answered.

Comment: @Tim: better now?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of normal letters there are strange symbols

As Rmano pointed out, you never can achieve 100% compatibility. However, the problem you describe sounds like being related to different fonts. So one first attempt would be either to agree on using fonts that are available on both platforms or installing the MS fonts on Ubuntu (the latter however, is not legal with the newer MS fonts if you don't have a Windows license).

Comment: Ms fonts are legal to use, they used to be a free download from the Micorsoft site.

Comment: @Rotomano I am referring to the likes of calibri etc., not Arial, Times New Roman etc. The licensing is quite different as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have enough info to answer your question. Are you using Libre office, and what version and on what ubuntu version?
However, as Bruni suggests, install Microsoft core fonts and try opening your documents again. They can be found in the UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER [**install the Ubuntu restricted extras**]. Install that package and come back if you still have any issues.